# Double click option can't find in elementary-os odin

Tags: release-odin

Hope you are doing well.
I recently shift from ubuntu to ele.os[odin].
I can't found the option to  activate  double click.

What I tried till now :

1. NO option in Pantheon tweaks
2. tried gsetting commands also like:

`gsettings set io.elementary.files.preferences single-click true`

Any suggestion will be really helpful[image]

Comment: Thanks, but It's not helping. There must be a way to hack eOS. I want a desktop but the single-click key doesn't in io.elementary.files.preferences key folder. There must be a way anyone knows?

Answer (score 3):

I found only one solution is **downgrade** file manager to prev version **4.5.0** where it is possible use double-click.

To do this follow the next instruction:

**1.** Remove current file manager

```
sudo apt remove pantheon-files
```

**2.** Download source code 4.5.0 version from link https://github.com/elementary/files/releases/tag/4.5.0

**3.** Install all packages to compile file manager from source code

```
sudo apt install meson valac libcanberra-dev libcloudproviders-dev libdbus-glib-1-dev libgail-3-dev libgee-0.8-dev libgit2-glib-1.0-dev libglib2.0-dev libgranite-dev libgtk-3-dev libhandy-1-dev libnotify-dev libpango1.0-dev libplank-dev libsqlite3-dev libunity-dev libzeitgeist-2.0-dev
```

**4.** In source code folder run the next commands

```
meson build --prefix=/usr
cd build
ninja
sudo ninja install
```

**5.** Now you have file manager 4.5.0 version that can be used with double click. To enable this option you need run

```
gsettings set io.elementary.files.preferences single-click false
```

**6.** Remove packages installed to compile file manager before.

```
sudo apt remove meson valac libcanberra-dev libcloudproviders-dev libdbus-glib-1-dev libgail-3-dev libgee-0.8-dev libgit2-glib-1.0-dev libglib2.0-dev libgranite-dev libgtk-3-dev libhandy-1-dev libnotify-dev libpango1.0-dev libplank-dev libsqlite3-dev libunity-dev libzeitgeist-2.0-dev
```

Now you can use elementary os file manages with double click.

Answer (score 1):

Double clicking to open folders has been disabled. There is now only the so-called „hybrid way:“ single click to open folders, double click to open files. There is no setting to change it.

Comment: it's sad though

Answer (score 1):

Any help how to disable single click on folder will be helpful.

Its really annoying that you can't change this settings now.

Answer (score 1):

As said earlier there is no way to achieve this with `io.elementary.files` on eOS 6 and 6.1.

Single click on folders it's a bad choice. I don't see any good reason for supporting it.

You realize how bad it is when you want to select a folder with mouse for deleting it. I'd like to know what eOS developers have to say about it.

I think `Nautilus` is a much better choice. The integration with eOS is easy.  Despite the single click issue `Nautilus` has also a much better `search` functionality.

Next system won't be eOS. I regret to say it although a followed and supported (financially) the project from the start.

Answer (score 1):

Double click to open folders has now been restored to Files, although mixed mode is still default.  You can turn on double click to select through the background context menu.

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem

For now, it is impossible (in conventional ways) to remove the single click on Pantheon Files (Elementary OS 6.1 Jolnir).

#### Solution

The solution I found, is to install the Nautilus file manager. It is very similar to Pantheon Files, and you can choose between one-click or double-click behaviour.

#### What you must to do

Just install and start using Nautilus instead of Pantheon Files.

#### How to

Just run the command below in a terminal:

```
sudo apt install -y nautilus
```

#### After installing...

1. Open Nautilus
2. Go to Nautilus settings
3. Choose the Preferences option
4. Go to the "Behavior" tab
5. Choose the option "Double Click to Open Items"

[image]

> That's the good side of Linux, if a tool doesn't give you what you want, you install another and solve your problem.

#### Compare

[image]